# Full Size iframe in smarty

Tags: html, powerbi, smarty, whmcs, template-literals

I have this embedded html iframe code

```
<iframe title="Sales-AdventureWork - Page 5" width="110%" height="100%" src="https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiOWFjOWZjYjAtY2RmYi00OGYxLTg2ZWYtNjQ5NjJkN2E5ODAzIiwidCI6ImUwYjNmMTA2LWU2Y2QtNDNjOS05NGUxLTRkMzMwMWNjZWMzOCIsImMiOjl9" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

for power bi reports, when I try to insert it into whmcs smarty (tpl) file it shows a partial frame not full size height and width like pic below

[image]

I need your help to show it in full size like the secound pic which works fine in html page .
[image]